# Is it ethical for me to post answers from some other source under my account on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, answers, ethics

I asked a question on Ask Ubuntu and also shared that question on Facebook. After that, some comments on Facebook gave me the answer I needed! But the users who gave me the answer have only Facebook accounts; they did not post on Ask Ubuntu.

Their answers solved my problem, so I would want them to be on the Ask Ubuntu website. Can I post their answers under my account? Is doing so ethical?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you post these answers as your own, then no, this is not ethical.

When someone posts an answer here, it is licensed as creative commons, with attribution required. Meaning that it is OK to post it elsewhere *so long as the source of the answer is acknowledged* (we ask for a link to the post and the name of the OP to be present).

As such, [we would expect the same to happen to any answer that came from elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

This means, that if you do post an answer to your question, which is not your original writing, you should attribute it - say where it came from and by whom (a link would be a nice extra).

Doing otherwise would also be considered plagiarism.

Comment: I agree with you. But facebook comments not have refference link. and posting answers by me is unethical, and that ansers also important. can I mention their name with my post? or never post that answers?

Comment: @MadhavNikam - you can link to the page / timeline, mention the answers were by others and provide the names. Make it possible to find the source.

Comment: thanks. I when I post anything others then I mentions that pages. and persons links. Link of that post.